# Financial Math - Compound Interest Rate

Tags: finance

I have `PV`, `PMT` and `N`. I want get `I` (Tax).

Please, if I'm not clear, help me adjust this Question. I don't know nothing about Financial Math. I'm programmer, I need get something like `TIR` function of Excel and recreate in `Python`. I just want the instruction.

**Example**

```
PV = 1.000
PMT = 80
N = 24
I = ????
```

The expected value of `I` is: `8.6%`

Comment: The English name for TIR [is](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=espanol-english.html) IRR. But this seems to be a question about Excel, not mathematics.

Comment: I is not tax, it is the interest rate!

Comment: Yes, interest rate. compound interest rate